# how to terminate an infinitely running process

Tags: operating-system

this question was asked to me in NVIDIA interview

Q)if a process is running from infinite time and O.S. has completely lost control on it, then how would you deallocate resources from that process?

Comment: What was your own answer?

Comment: @Macmade i said either through any hardware interrupt or by restarting the system. But i don't know either these answers are correct or not

Comment: What is meant by the OS completely losing control of the process?

Comment: @ArlieStephens it means that OS can't deallocate resourses from that process

Comment: is there any hints of your interviewer?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very open question for which the answer depends on lot of factors like signal mechanism of the OS, fork wait exit are implemented, states in which a process can be ...etc. Your answers should have been on the following lines.

A process can be in 1 of these states: ready, running, waiting.. apart from this there is born state and terminated/zombie state. During its lifetime i.e after fork() till exit(), a process has system resources under its control. Ex:entries in process table, open files to IO devices, VM allocated, mappings in page table etc...

**OS has lost complete control of the process**: I interpret as follows--

**-----** A process can execute a system call Ex-read and the OS will put the process into sleep/waiting state. There are 2 kinds of sleep: **INTERRUPTIBLE & UNINTERRUPTIBLE** 
After the read is done the Hardware sends a signal to the OS which will get redirected to the sleeping process. And the process will spring up to action again. There may also be a case where the read never completed so the Hardware never sent a signal.

Assume the process initiated a read (which will fail) and went to a:

**a INTERRUPTIBLE SLEEP:**   Now the OS/parent of this process can send a SIGSTOP, SIGKILL etc to this process and it will be interrupted from its sleep and then the OS can kill the process reclaim all the resources. This is fine and solves your problem of infinite resource control.

**b UNINTERRUPTIBLE SLEEP:**  Now even though the read has not sent any signal, but is taking infinite time, and the parent/OS knows that the read has failed likely sending SIGSTOP,SIGKILL has no effect since it is sleeping UNITERRUPTIBLY waiting for read to finish. So now the process has control over system resource and OS cant claim it back. See [this](http://justlinux.ca/tips/UninterruptableSleep) for clear understanding of UNITERRUPTIBLE SLEEP. So, if a process is in this state from an infinite time, the OS or parent **CANNOT** kill/stop it and reclaim the resource, those resources are tied indefinitely and can be reclaimed only when the system is **powered off**, or you need to hack the driver where a service is struck and get it terminated by the driver which will then send the read failed signal to UNINTERRUPTIBLE PROCESS.

**-----** after the process has completed its execution and ready to die, the parent which created this process has not yet called wait on this child and process is in ZOMBIE state, in which case it is still hanging on to some system resources. Usually it is the job of the parent to ensure that the child it created terminates normally. But, it may be the case that the parent which was supposed to call wait on this child itself got killed, then the onus of terminating this child goes to the OS, that is exactly what init process does on UNIX like OSes. Apart from its other jobs, init acts like a foster parent for the process whoes parent are dead. It runs the check_ZOMBIE procedures every now and then ( when system resources are low) to ensure that ZOMBIES dont hang on to system resources.

From the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) : When a process loses its parent, init becomes its new parent. Init periodically executes the wait system call to reap any zombies with init as parent. One of init's responsibilities is reaping orphans and parentless zombies.

So your answer should be pointing at the way process states are defined, signal handling mechanisms are implemented and also the way init process reaps ZOMBIES etc ....

Hope it cleared a thing or two..

Cheers....